# Special for syntax for looping over all objects of a certain class?

Tags: for-loop, swift

Can I compress this combined `for`-plus-`if` into a single `for`,

i.e. can I combine the first two lines into a single instruction for a loop?

It should visit only those objects in `childNodes` that are instances of `MyNode`.

```
for childNode in childNodes {
    if let myNode = childNode as? MyNode {
         // do something with myNode
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that `childNodes` is an array. If yes, then you can filter it:

```
for childNode in (childNodes.filter { $0 is MyNode }) {
    println ("It's a node")
}
```

or if you prefer more explicit code:

```
let nodes = childNodes.filter { $0 is MyNode }
for childNode in nodes {
    println ("It's a node")
}
```

As far as I know, in swift there's no clean way to combine a `for` loop with optional binding to skip some iterations.

Something might be possible using a standard `for` loop, combined with a closure which, given an index, returns the next index containing a `MyNode` instance... but I wouldn't call it a simplification in terms of code and readability:

```
let findNext = { (var index: Int) -> (node: MyNode?, next: Int) in
    while index < childNodes.count {
        if let node = childNodes[index] as? MyNode {
            return (node, index)
        }
        ++index
    }

    return (nil, index)
}

for var (node, index) = findNext(0); node != nil; (node, index) = findNext(index + 1) {
    println ("it's a node: \(node!)")
}
```

Comment: This will build a whole new array, which seems a bit too high a cost.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I don't think there is any way to combine the `for` with the optional binding.

Comment: If you can confirm that there is no such `for` and put it in your answer, I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let nodes = childNodes.filter({ $0 is MyNode }).map({ $0 as MyNode }) // Array<MyNode>
for node in nodes {
   ...
}
```

If you don't like intermediate array creation, the folloing is the solution, but maybe slower than above one.

```
//          ↓
let nodes = lazy(childNodes).filter({ $0 is MyNode }).map({ $0 as MyNode }) // nodes: LazySequence<MapSequenceView<FilterSequenceView<[Any]>, MyNode>>
for node in nodes {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thx for mentioning lazy. But I'd still not bring in that amount of overhead as alternative to original version. If there is no more condensed `for`-syntax available, I'll probably stick with it.